# const works but does not constexpr

Tags: c++, constants, constexpr

This a scratching my head question, but it works, with const, but not constexpr and I'm wondering if you smart folks can explain. Compiled with g++ -std=c++14.

```
struct Service
{
    std::string name;
    enum {
        thread,
        interrupt,
        end_types
    } que_type;
};

const Service namedServices[] =
{
    {"abc", Service::thread},
    {"efg", Service::thread},
    {"hij", Service::interrupt},
    {"klm", Service::thread},
    {"nop", Service::interrupt},
    {"qrs", Service::thread},
    {"", Service::end_types}
};

constexpr int thcnt()
{
    int cnt = 0;
    for (const Service* sp = namedServices; sp->que_type != Service::end_types; sp++) {
        if (sp->que_type == Service::thread)
            cnt++;
    }
    return cnt;
}
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    std::string strs[thcnt()];
 ...
```

This compiles and as far as I can tell does the right thing.  If I change to

```
constexpr Service namedServices[] =
```

I get

```
... error: the type 'const Service []' of constexpr variable 'namedServices' is not literal
 };
 ^
```

This seems weird, but perhaps there is a good reason.  Or maybe, it will be fixed in c++20.

thanks

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`namedServices` is not a [LiteralType](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/LiteralType) since it's an array of class containing `std::string` which is not a LiteralType. Therefore it cannot be `constexpr`.

Note that your `thcnt()` function actually causes undefined behaviour with no diagnostic required, because it has no cases of constant evaluation due to `namedServices` not having constant evaluation; and `std::string strs[thcnt()];` only passes if you have VLAs enabled which g++ does by default. Use `-pedantic` to get ISO conformance.

As of C++20 there will be [`consteval` specifier](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/consteval) to cause a compilation error instead of UB NDR, this is supported by [clang trunk (example)](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/-e8nFC) .

---

I have seen some suggestion that C++20 will have `constexpr std::string` however clang trunk (godbolt edition, at least) currently does not support that, and C++20 has not quite been finalized yet. It may be that your code becomes legal in C++20.

In the meantime you can make the code legal by using `constexpr Service namedServices[]` and:

- In C++14 or later, by using `const char *name;`
- In C++17, by using `std::string_view name;`

Comment: IIRC, `std::string_view` is a literal type, right, so it could work with that instead? Or would it need to actually drop down to `const char*`?

Comment: @DanielH That views on some other object that already exists , so I don't think it is a solution to OP's problem

Comment: (Update: According to cppreference (can’t check the draft standard right now), all `std::string_view` constructors and `operator""sv` are already `constexpr`, and in C++20 `operator""s` will be but not any `std::string` constructors.)

Comment: It can view on string literals, as in the example; that may or may not be a solution given the actual code.

Comment: @DanielH I see , have added that to my answer now. The compiler seems to accept the string_view version in C++17 mode so I'll trust that is correct

Comment: Thanks all, C++17 it is then.  FYI, I've only come back to C++ in the last year after the last 12 in python land.  I'm slowing educating myself as I implement.